# Secure pages return 404 after migration

Tags: nginx, 404-page, server-setup

After copying and moving my site to a staging.domain.com spot on the same server. The frontend works but all of my secure pages (admin, login, checkout etc) pages return an Nginx 404. I've made an exact copy of my live environment and imported the database, and of course changed the base urls.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a `.htaccess` *misconfiguration*. Some redirects may also reside in the server configuration. Maybe there are wildcard-redirects for "admin" and similar. If you simply copied the mage-directory make sure that [your NGINX likes and uses .htaccess](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/).

I guess you deleted your Magento-cache?

Comment: I've deleted my caches every time I've made a change. This is my htaccess:

Comment: `.htaccess` contents have not been parsed. try wrapping it in `<pre></pre> `-code or use backticks.